# How to download pdf file by using twig when device is in mobile?

Tags: twig

I am using the twig to do the report template but now I face a problem. Since I download `pdf` by using twig template and it is successfully downloaded, but when I change to a mobile device, it does not run the download `pdf` file function. I need  toadd some code or change the code? Below is my code,I used `php` file

On my php file

```php
$view = $request->getParameter('view');

-----Calling mysql--------

$loader = new FilesystemLoader(__DIR__ . '/../../templates');
$twig = new Environment($loader);
$html = $twig->render('COR.html.twig', ['dsCompany'=>$dsCompany,'dsCustomerInfo'=>$dsCustomerInfo,'dsOutstandingAging'=>$dsOutstandingAging,'dsOutstandingSummary'=>$dsOutstandingSummary,'dsChequeSummary'=>$dsChequeSummary]);

if($view != null){
    $mpdf = new Mpdf(['format' => 'A4-P']);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    return $this->response->build(200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="mpdf.pdf"'
    ], $mpdf->Output());
}else{
    return $this->response->build(200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html'
    ],$html);
}
```

on my js file

```
<iron-ajax id="xhrView" url="" loading="{{loading}}" on-response="_viewResponse" on-error="_serviceError" content-type="application/json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{services}}"></iron-ajax>

view_report(){
this.$.xhrView.url = MSAppGlobals.apiPath + 'ReportView/' + this.routeData.report_id + '?company_code=' + this.$.filter.children.companyCode.value + '&order_id=' + this.$.filter.children.orderID.value + '&filter=' + this.userInfo.permissions.Report.filter_data;
this.$.xhrView.method = 'GET';
this.$.xhrView.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.userInfo.token;
this.$.xhrView.handleAs = 'text';
this.$.xhrView.generateRequest();
}

save_report(){
var view = "save";
this.$.xhrView.url = MSAppGlobals.apiPath + 'ReportView/' + this.routeData.report_id + '?company_code=' + this.$.filter.children.companyCode.value + '&order_id=' + this.$.filter.children.orderID.value + '&view=' + view + '&filter=' + this.userInfo.permissions.Report.filter_data;
this.$.xhrView.method = 'GET';
this.$.xhrView.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.userInfo.token;
this.$.xhrView.handleAs = 'blob';
this.$.xhrView.generateRequest();
}

_viewResponse(){
        var contentType = this.$.xhrView.lastRequest.xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        var contentDisposition =  this.$.xhrView.lastRequest.xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');<--return back 'inline'-->

        if(contentType == 'application/pdf'){
            var filename = this.report.report_name + '.pdf';

            var blob = new Blob([this.$.xhrView.lastResponse]);

            var a = window.document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, {type: contentType});
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        } else {
            this.$.viewer.innerHTML = this.$.xhrView.lastResponse;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: js and php file

Comment: I mean, are you using like symfone, silex, ... ? Where is `$this->response->build` comming from

Comment: $this->response->build come from polymer

Comment: and use fusio to control the sql data

Comment: Where does `$view` come from? How is it calculated? As you're returning `Content-Type: text/html` if that variable has the value `null` this is likely the cause of your pdf not downloading on mobile.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich $view is call from js file when i pass the view parameter to php, on my js file is all handle the GET,POST and etc response

Comment: Describe your problem more detailed please and add all the relevant code to the question. Complete controller-action and relevant javascript. Does the PDF *open* but not *download* on mobile or what's happening exactly?

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich i updated, on mobile when i click download button, it did not have any response to me, but when i change back to windows, it's work, only mobile cannot

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `Content-Disposition` header for the PDF to download:

```
return $this->response->build(200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"'
], $mpdf->Output());
```

Comment: hmm, the 'Content-Dispostion' is use for what?

Comment: It tells the Browser to either (try to) render **or** download the resource. Just google it. A download makes sense in your case.

Comment: even i put the ''Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"'' on the response, when i calling getResponseHeader on js file, it still auto change back to 'Content-Disposition = "inline; filename="mpdf.pdf"" '

Comment: i tried but it no work on chrome, after i click save it also no response anything